# How to access the section titles in toc in order to format with tcolorbox

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox, titletoc

I would like to put both the section number and the title of the section in the table of contents into a \tcolorbox. While this works easily for the number, I don't know how to access the name of the title in order to put it in a box. Is there an easy solution for this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}%section
[0pc]%left
{}%above
{\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green,width=1cm,sharp corners,nobeforeafter]
    \thecontentslabel
    \end{tcolorbox}}
{} 
{}
[]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{section title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to format the whole entry of a toc title or you want to do that for individual parts of the entry (e.g., number, title, page number are all with different tcolorbox?)

Comment: I wanted to place the number and title in different boxes and finally succeeded. But now I have a second problem: Is there a way to use tcolorbox in manually added toc entries using \addcontentsline?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following solution:

```
\newcommand\tocbox[1]%
{\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white, colback=blue!15,nobeforeafter,sharp corners,left=1.2cm,top=0.1cm,height=0.7cm,width=15.77cm,enhanced,boxrule=0pt]
        \bfseries\color{blue}#1\hfill\contentspage
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}
\titlecontents{section}[0pc]
{\vspace*{0.2cm}\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue,colframe=white,width=0.7cm,height=0.7cm,left=0.13cm,top=0.07cm,sharp corners,extrude right by=0.1cm,nobeforeafter,enhanced,boxrule=0pt]
    \Large\bfseries\color{white}\thecontentslabel
    \end{tcolorbox}}
{\tocbox} % the second argument is left implicit
{}
{}
```