# Formatting manually entered toc entries with tcolorbox

Tags: table-of-contents, environments, tcolorbox, page-numbering, titletoc

Followup to [How to access the section titles in toc in order to format with tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/703205/)

I would like to put a manually entered toc entry using \addcontentsline in a tcolorbox. However, I am confused how to place the page number correctly. Note: I do not want to change this globally (I know how this works with titletoc) but I want this only for single entries. Thanks for your help!

I would like the toc line to look like this:
[image: example toc line]

This is my code:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\texorpdfstring{\tocboxm{\rlap{Research Areas}}}{}}
```

where I define \tocboxm as follows:

```
\newcommand\tocboxm[1]%
{\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white, colback=blue!15,nobeforeafter,sharp corners,top=0.1cm,height=0.7cm,width=12.77cm,enhanced,boxrule=0pt]
        \bfseries\color{blue}#1\hfill\contentspage
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}
```

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301026/36296 could be helpful

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how this might help, since I only want to do this manually for single entries, not all chapters.

Comment: Oh, maybe you can explicitly mention this in your question. I assumed the manual formatting was just a hack to get the tcolorbox in.

Comment: Thanks, I added that. I hope it is clearer now. Do you have any idea how to fix this nicely?

Comment: Thanks, much clearer now!

Comment: Please link relevant earlier questions, whether your own or others'.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to manually add the toc entries for star version of `\section` command. I think this will achieve what you wanted. Remember you should provide a MWE for each question you asked. This way you will more likely to get a answer. Because we don't need to guess what packages you use and what do you want to achieve.

Because the subsection toc entry will have different style than section entry. So, `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{...}` will mess up the format of tcolorbox `\tocboxm` you defined unless you redefine the `\subsection` style using `\titlecontents` (like you did for `section`). So, instead you could use `\addtocontents{toc}{...}` to fully customize the toc entry for you. However, in this way, you need manually create hyper links for this entry using `hypertarget{label}{content}` and `hyperlink{label}{content}`.

I made some tweaks to the tocolorbox settings. Your previous settings make the box out of the margin. You could check the margin boundary using package `showframe`. From the below example, you can see the boxes were aligned better inside the text area right now.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand\tocbox[1]%
{\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white, colback=blue!15,nobeforeafter,sharp corners,left=1.2cm,top=0.1cm,height=0.7cm,width=\linewidth-0.7cm,enhanced,boxrule=0pt]
        \bfseries\color{blue}#1\hfill\thecontentspage
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\newcommand\tocboxm[1]%
{\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white, colback=blue!15,nobeforeafter,sharp corners,top=0.1cm,height=0.7cm,width=\linewidth,left=1.9cm,enhanced,boxrule=0pt]
        \bfseries\color{blue}#1\hfill\thepage%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
\par}

\titlecontents{section}[0pc]
{\vspace{0.2cm}\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue,colframe=white,width=0.7cm,height=0.7cm,left=0cm,right=0pt,top=0.07cm,sharp corners,extrude right by=0.1cm,nobeforeafter,enhanced,boxrule=0pt]
    \Large\bfseries\color{white}\centering\thecontentslabel
    \end{tcolorbox}}
{\tocbox} % the second argument is left implicit
{}
{}
\makeatletter
\let\profileper\protected@file@percent
\makeatother

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Section Title}
This page contents...
\clearpage
\hypertarget{fakesec1}{\section*{Research Areas}}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\tocboxm{\protect\hyperlink{fakesec1}{Research Areas}}}%
This page contents...
\section{Testing}
\end{document}
```

[image]